# iOS imageView.image cannot fill the view when adding using code but works fine by storyboard

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tableview

I want to add an image to imageView in the cell, when adding by storyboard, it can fill the imageView, but when adding using code, it always has a white space in left. Does anyone have idea about it? Thanks.

Here is my code:

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: try using .ScaleAspectFill instead of .ScaleAspectFit .

Comment: @sourav changed, but not work

Comment: @sourav yes, I used auto layout

Comment: @sourav edited the question, add the constrains picture. I set the imageView to be the same size as cell's contentView

Comment: Use this code .          cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "space")
        cell.imageView!.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        cell.imageView!.frame = cell.frame

Comment: @sourav I solved the issue. It seems add another view when use cell.imageView!.image. I added the answer below. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I used debug view hierarchy in Xcode to check the view, found there are two imageView! But there is just one imageView in storyboard. Seems set image via storyboard set the image on second imageView and set the image via code set the image on first imageView.

[image][image][image]

So I change the code to:

```
let imageView = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "space")
```

Then it works. Checked the debug again, it just one imageView there. So it seems cell.imageView!.image add an imageView above the imageView. I still cannot figure out why this will happen...

Comment: because if you go inside UITableviewCell and UICollectionViewCell they have a class variable **public var imageView: UIImageView? { get }**  , So it was creating instance of that imageView .

Comment: @sourav so in future, if we want to use our own imageView instead of the class variable, it would better to set a tag for  out imageView or creat a IBOutlet for reference?

Comment: yes, you have to create IBOutlet for the imageView .